# Magento 2: Add border-radius to image on product page

Tags: magento2, product-images, product-page, styles, custom-template

Magento 2.2.1 using a custom theme which inherets from `Magento/blank`.

I would like to add a border-radius to the main image on the product page.

I have tried applying border-radius to parent containers without success, but the image itself is loaded with fotorama and I'm not sure how to cleanly alter the styles for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JoshuaFlood first you need to inspect the image tag on your browser to get the right image class, then you can style it like this:

```
.fotorama__stage__frame .fotorama__img{
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to more cleanly alter the fotorama plugin or override its styles natively?

I feel like I should be declaring styles for particular modules, rather than filling up my `Magento_Theme` _extends.less file with page-specific styles.

Comment: I had assumed this as a last resort, but I expected that magento would handle one of their most crucial models a bit more cleanly.